# Problem with "id" parameter on page with apex:relatedList

Tags: visualforce

I have a simple Visualforce page that has the following:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
   <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}"/><br />
   <apex:relatedList subject="{!Account.Contacts}" list="AccountContactRoles"/>
</apex:page>
```

When I navigate to the page it gives me the following error.

> **Unable to Access Page**
>
> The value of the "id" parameter contains a character that is not
>   allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the
>   character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and
>   resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer
>   Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well
>   as any other related information.

I am specifying a valid Account ID in the URL:

```
https://c.na14.visual.force.com/apex/contacts?id=001d000000VtORJ
```

When I remove the [`<apex:relatedList>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm) the page renders with the Account Name correctly.

Is there some other parameter or value that I need for the [`<apex:relatedList>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm) when used with a child?  I don't ever remember needing anything else.

I'm in a DE that is Winter '13.

Comment: I removed the Subject Attribute and tried. It worked. Dont know what that means, but just FYI.

Comment: In your example i think you need to correct `{!Account.Contacts}` to `{!Account.Contacts[0]}` because apex:relatedList `subject` expected ID value of the record. I have tried this, but then I got another problem: `'AccountContactRoles' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Contact`. After research i found that `AccountContactRoles` related list on the Contact object is not visible for some reason :( Here some info: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Best-Practices-Discussion/accounts-contact-roles/td-p/99292

Comment: @mast0r - Thanks!  That's interesting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My error...what I really wanted was the related list of each contact.  Something like the following:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
       <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}"/><br />
       <apex:repeat value="{!Account.Contacts}" var="contact">
           <apex:outputText value="{!contact.Name}"/>
           <apex:relatedList subject="{!contact}" list="AccountContactRoles"/>
       </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

I was incorrectly specifying a List as the subject, when I needed an object.